# Match only character set from the same language (like facebook name)?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match

```
preg_match(???, 'firstname lastname') // true;
preg_match(???, '서프 누워') // true;
preg_match(???, '서프 lastname') // false;
preg_match(???, '#$@ #$$#') // false;
```

Currently I use:

```
'/^([一-龠0-9\s]+|[ぁ-ゔ0-9\s]+|[ก-๙0-9\s]+|[ァ-ヴー0-9\s]+|[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+|[々〆〤0-9\s]+)$/u'
```

But it only works on some languages.

Comment: how about you use \w\s+\w

Comment: This is an interesting question. Does it not work for some of the languages you define in the regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an expression that will match only characters from the same [unicode script](http://codepoints.net/scripts) (and spaces), like:

```
 ^([\p{SomeScript} ]+|[\p{SomeOtherScript} ]+|...)$
```

You can build this expression dynamically from the list of scripts:

```
$scripts = "Hangul Hiragana Han Latin Cyrillic"; // feel free to add more

$re = [];
foreach(explode(' ', $scripts) as $s)
    $re [] = sprintf('[\p{%s} ]+', $s);
$re = "~^(" . implode("|", $re) . ")$~u";

print preg_match($re, 'firstname lastname'); // 1
print preg_match($re, '서프 누워'); // 1
print preg_match($re, '서프 lastname'); // 0
print preg_match($re, '#$@ #$$#'); // 0
```

Do note however, that it's common for names (at least, in European scripts I'm familiar with) to include characters like dots, dashes and apostrophes, which belong to the "Common" script rather than to a language-specific one. To take these into account, a more realistic version of a "chunk" in the above expression could be like this:

```
 ((\p{SomeScript}+(\. ?|[ '-]))*\p{SomeScript}+)
```

which will at least correctly validate `L. A. Léon de Saint-Just`.

In general, validating people's names is a complicated problem and cannot be solved with 100% accuracy. See [this funny post](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and comments therein for details and examples.

Comment: +1, it's the only approach I can think of (without manually defining the sets). But sometimes the unicode scripts are just too generic. Just consider Latin (http://codepoints.net/search?sc[]=Latn) which has 1641 codepoints from which each language only uses a small subset of them.

Comment: Also, it includes codepoints like (example from Latin) `FULL WIDTH SMALL LETTER *` which you obviously don't like to see in a name... But as this'll be impossible to check, just forget checking more precisely, the best you can do in this case is what you did — checking character classes.